# How can I boot off an external I.E. Non-flash hard drive from BIOS?

Tags: boot, bios

I made a backup of my windows 10 computer using the built-in windows utility.

I've been installed a program that broke all of my USB ports, so I cannot log into my computer.

I want to boot off this drive, which is not a small thumb, USB, Flash drive  but a large platter drive.

When I boot into the BIOS it does not appear as a bootable option, even though it shows up in the "boot menu"

Why is this, and is there a way for me to make it appear in the boot order portion of the bios?

Comment: Are you sure the backup is bootable? Because the firmware usually doesn't care about the difference.

Comment: I am not entirely sure – and I do not know how to verify. Buy used windows back up utilities so I assumed it was good to go

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Windows backup, the backup disk isn't bootable. 
You will need to use a Windows DVD to boot the machine, or make a recovery disk on another windows machine, then restore your backup from your USB disk.

If the drive isn't showing up as a bootable option, it is likely that there is no valid boot loader on the drive but as it's showing up in the boot menu, it means that the BIOS can at least see the disk.

You can use the recovery disk to make a bootable USB recovery disk which can boot the machine, then launch the restore tool.
If you use this recovery disk as your backup disk, you will have a bootable backup and restore solution on one disk.

For now though, unless you have a windows DVD, you will need to make a recovery disk on another machine.

Your USB disk backup should be fine to restore from.

https://www.raymond.cc/blog/create-windows-7-system-image-for-full-backup-and-restoration/